# Looping Through a1 to h8

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some text fields inside objects a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1   a2 b2 c2...

```
num = 97;
while (num <= 104) {
    if (this[String.fromCharCode(num) + "1"].piece == wb1_txt) {
        oldSquare = String.fromCharCode(num) + "1";
        trace("oldSquare = ", oldSquare);
    }
    num = num + 1;
}
```

I want to find text field's location. How can I make it loop?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you're trying to do. Do you want to trace the location of every TextField that can be found as a Rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will go through a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 f1 g1 h1 a2 b2 ... g8 h8

```
for( i=1; i<=8; i++){
    for( num=97; num<105; num++){
        sq = String.fromCharCode(num) + i;
        trace( sq );
    }
}
```